# Cookie domain limits

Tags: http, cookies

According to RFC2109, some agent may limit the cookie for a given domain.

I'm not totally sure about the domain limitation for this case:

- cookie A issued for Domain=.mydomain.com
- cookie B issued for Domain=foo.mydomain.com
- cookie C issued for Domain=bar.mydomain.com

since cookie A will be visible/sent also to "foo.mydomain.com" and "bar.mydomain.com", does the cookie A affect the limitations for all deeper Domain(s) or the limit rule simply apply according to the value (as is) of the Domain parameter?

IOW the limit for domain foo.mydomain.com will be counted only on cookie B or A+B?

Comment: you're setting domain for every particular cookie, ie value, so domain set for one cookie will not affect domain set for another cookie

Answer (score 0):

Please do not rely on RFC2109 any longer as it has been out of date since 2000. The current RFC6265 recommends in [section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-6.1) clients store *at least* 50 cookies per domain.

As for your concern: This really is a recommendation only and clients cannot be forced to store *any cookies at all*. However, for those that do keep state, I usually see a storage model that relies on the originating domain instead of the one set in the `Set-Cookie` header. So when it comes to limits being applied, I think it is safe to assume they are being taxed per originating domain.

Comment: "originating domain" I assume you mean the real domain/host that issued the cookie regardless the Domain cookie parameter. If so how can I get that "originating domain" through the browser/developer tool? For ex. in chrome could be Resources -> Cookies? All cookies listed within each item will be counted for that "originating domain"?

Comment: Yes, when I wrote originating domain, I actually meant issuing domain. Sorry for being unclear. As for 3rd party cookies: My guess is they will tax the limits of the domain specified by the `Set-Cookie` header. Local storage of these is vendor specific, but looking at the `cookie.sqlite` of Firefox, I would say it is not possible to identify those without context. Likewise I see no way to do so in chrome.